# Adonis 5 node deprecated warning when using migration

Tags: node.js, typescript, adonisjs-ace

This has recently started poping up in commandline....anyone know whats going on, Im unsure why the new package in node_modules is not compatable with node v14.16. I tried using older version of node (docs state min version for adonis 5 is version 12), although this produces a syntax error.

This `container.with() is deprecated` warning shows whenever using the node ace commands. How can I fix these?

**Node version 14.16.0:**

```
node --trace-warnings ace migration:rollback
(node:24088) container.with() is deprecated. Use container.withBindings() instead: DeprecationWarning
    at Ioc.with (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js:421:17)
    at DatabaseServiceProvider.registerHealthChecker (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\providers\DatabaseProvider.js:93:32)
    at DatabaseServiceProvider.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\providers\DatabaseProvider.js:140:14)
    at Registrar.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Registrar\index.js:116:32)
    at C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:543:13
    at Profiler.profileAsync (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\node_modules\@adonisjs\profiler\build\src\Profiler\AbstractProfiler.js:20:32)
    at Application.bootProviders (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:541:9)
    at App.wire (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:192:9)
    at App.onFind (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:145:13)
    at Hooks.execute (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Hooks\index.js:44:13)
(node:24088) container.with() is deprecated. Use container.withBindings() instead: DeprecationWarning
    at Ioc.with (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js:421:17)
    at DatabaseServiceProvider.defineValidationRules (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\providers\DatabaseProvider.js:109:32)
    at DatabaseServiceProvider.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\build\providers\DatabaseProvider.js:141:14)
    at Registrar.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Registrar\index.js:116:32)
    at C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:543:13
    at Profiler.profileAsync (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\node_modules\@adonisjs\profiler\build\src\Profiler\AbstractProfiler.js:20:32)
    at Application.bootProviders (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:541:9)
    at App.wire (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:192:9)
    at App.onFind (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:145:13)
    at Hooks.execute (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Hooks\index.js:44:13)
(node:24088) container.with() is deprecated. Use container.withBindings() instead: DeprecationWarning
    at Ioc.with (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js:421:17)
    at AuthProvider.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\build\providers\AuthProvider.js:32:40)
    at Registrar.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Registrar\index.js:116:32)
    at C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:543:13
    at Profiler.profileAsync (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\node_modules\@adonisjs\profiler\build\src\Profiler\AbstractProfiler.js:20:32)
    at Application.bootProviders (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:541:9)
    at App.wire (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:192:9)
    at App.onFind (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:145:13)
    at Hooks.execute (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Hooks\index.js:44:13)
    at Kernel.find (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Kernel\index.js:371:13)
(node:24088) container.with() is deprecated. Use container.withBindings() instead: DeprecationWarning
    at Ioc.with (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\index.js:421:17)
    at AuthProvider.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\build\providers\AuthProvider.js:37:40)
    at Registrar.boot (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Registrar\index.js:116:32)
    at C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:543:13
    at Profiler.profileAsync (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\node_modules\@adonisjs\profiler\build\src\Profiler\AbstractProfiler.js:20:32)
    at Application.bootProviders (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:541:9)
    at App.wire (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:192:9)
    at App.onFind (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\Ace\App\index.js:145:13)
    at Hooks.execute (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Hooks\index.js:44:13)
    at Kernel.find (C:\project\node_modules\@adonisjs\ace\build\src\Kernel\index.js:371:13)
```

**Node version 12.5.0:**

```
node ace migration:rollback
C:\project\node_modules\@poppinss\utils\build\src\Helpers\string.js:241
        return `${values[0]}${options?.pairSeparator || ' and '}${values[1]}`;
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project\node_modules\@poppinss\utils\build\src\Helpers\index.js:56:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after updating to latest 'release' version of adonis 5 this issue has been resolved. Stupid preview issues

Answer (score 0):

`@poppinss\utils\build\src\Helpers\string.js:241` uses [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which is only supported from Node.js 14

[image: optional chaining compatibility grid]

Using Node.js v14.15 will fix the problem.
I personally had this problem with Node.js 12 and Node.js 14.16. I switched to Node.js v14.15.1 and it worked instantly.

Comment: Thanks..I tired using the v14.15.1, but this is the same as v14.16 and I still get the 'container.with() is deprecated' warning, from the @adonisjs files.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Lucid package. Running npm i @adonisjs/lucid@latest solves the issue.